# "Who" usage in sentence

Tags: who-that

> Mr. Kejriwal has already broached the subject with Mr. Modi, who has been non-committal.

In the above sentence, please tell if ***who*** is **indicated** to Mr. Modi or to Mr. Kejriwal.

If it is indicated to Mr. Modi, what if I want to indicate to Mr. Kejriwal, what would the sentence be?

Thanks in advanced.

Thanks,
Charmi.

Comment: Unless there is a clear indication otherwise, the relative pronouns relate to the appropriate noun preceding closest: therefore Mr. Modi.

Comment: Thank you Scot, Is it possible for you to give a sentence in which the relative pronouns relate to the appropriate noun is not close to it (the appropriate noun)? This is my humble request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

who/which/where etc directly refers to the noun/word before.  So in the cited case, it should be 'Mr Modi'

Comment: Thank you for clarifying and it always comes after noun/word right or is there any exception?

Answer (score 0):

As for your second question, one way is to reverse the clauses thus:

Mr. Kejriwal, who has been non-committal, has already broached the subject with Mr. Modi.